# Получаю ошибку при переворачивании числа

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Задача с литкода

https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/submissions/

Мое решение

```
public int Reverse(int x) {
      int rev = 0;
        while (x != 0)
        {
            int temp = x % 10;
            x /= 10;
            rev = rev * 10 + temp;
            if (rev > Int32.MaxValue)
                return 0;
        }
        return rev;
}
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку http://prntscr.com/m7k176

Обьясните, пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как это пофиксить.

Comment: Проверять, что будет переполнение, нужно до умножения

Comment: Тут встроенный хостинг для картинок - используй его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Что раньше - курица или яйцо?*

```
if (rev > Int32.MaxValue)
```

Число "девять миллиардов" не поместится в четырехбайтовое целое. Поэтому ожидаемый результат - ноль.

Целое число типа `Int32`  не может содержать значение больше, чем максимальное значение целого числа типа `Int32`. Это проверка не делает то, что Вы думаете. Вернее, сравнение в Вашем `if` всегда возвращает `false`.

```
if (rev > Int32.MaxValue / 10 || Int32.MaxValue - temp < rev * 10)
  return 0;

rev = rev * 10 + temp;
```

Comment: все еще не понимаю. обьясни, пожалуйста

Comment: @VladimirNeutrino Сейчас.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @VladimirNeutrino На здоровье. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться конструкцией [checked](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked)

`checked` выбрасывает исключение в случае выхода за пределы диапазона типа при выполнении арифметического действия